# Swift Best Way to Save CGMutablePath as JSON

Tags: swift, cgpath

What is the best way to save a CGMutablePath as JSON data that can be uploaded to backend?

I'm aware that it could be converted into a `Data` object using `UIBezierPath` which conforms to NSCoding, then the data could be converted again to a string and saved to backend, but that doesn't seem like a great way. Is there a better way to save this object to backend?

Perhaps you could pull out the huge array of points that make up the path, convert it into a string and save that. Would this be best?

Comment: "Best way" is very ambiguous. Saving it as `Data` will be enough, but is good for your use case? We don't know because we don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Generally, storing raw data in a backend is not what you want to do. There are far fewer options to compress raw blob data vs readable json data on a backend.

Comment: I agree, but we don't know how you're using `CGMutablePath` so there isn't a good answer that we can give you. I could tell you that it's best to store points, but maybe you need to also support curves, arcs, etc.

Comment: It's being used to create a drawing along the path, so curves etc are needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CGPath` or `CGMutablePath` is a very simple data structure. It's an array of path elements. An each path elements is either a *move*, *line*, *cubicCurve*, *curve* or *closeSubpath* operation with 0 to 3 points. That's all. There are no additional attributes or variants.

So it's quite straight-forward to translate a path into an array of path element (`struct PathElement`) and then encode it as JSON. It results in a JSON that can be easily read with any programming language and works on many graphics systems (incl. iOS/macOS Quartz, Postscript, PDF, Windows GDI+).

The output of the below sample code consists of the printed `CGMutablePath`, the generated JSON and the path restored from JSON:

```
Path 0x10100d960:
  moveto (10, 10)
    lineto (30, 30)
    quadto (100, 100) (200, 200)
    curveto (150, 120) (100, 350) (20, 400)
    closepath
  moveto (200, 200)
    lineto (230, 230)
    lineto (260, 210)
    closepath

[
  {
    "type" : 0,
    "points" : [
      [
        10,
        10
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "type" : 1,
    "points" : [
      [
        30,
        30
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "type" : 2,
    "points" : [
      [
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        200,
        200
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "type" : 3,
    "points" : [
      [
        150,
        120
      ],
      [
        100,
        350
      ],
      [
        20,
        400
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "type" : 4
  },
  {
    "type" : 0,
    "points" : [
      [
        200,
        200
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "type" : 1,
    "points" : [
      [
        230,
        230
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "type" : 1,
    "points" : [
      [
        260,
        210
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "type" : 4
  }
]

Path 0x10100bd20:
  moveto (10, 10)
    lineto (30, 30)
    quadto (100, 100) (200, 200)
    curveto (150, 120) (100, 350) (20, 400)
    closepath
  moveto (200, 200)
    lineto (230, 230)
    lineto (260, 210)
    closepath
```

Sample code:

```
import Foundation

var path = CGMutablePath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), control: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 400), control1: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 120), control2: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 350))
path.closeSubpath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 230, y: 230))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 260, y: 210))
path.closeSubpath()
print(path)

let jsonData = encode(path: path)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)
print("")

let restoredPath = try! decode(data: jsonData)
print(restoredPath)


func encode(path: CGPath) -> Data {
    var elements = [PathElement]()
    
    path.applyWithBlock() { elem in
        let elementType = elem.pointee.type
        let n = numPoints(forType: elementType)
        var points: Array<CGPoint>?
        if n > 0 {
            points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: elem.pointee.points, count: n))
        }
        elements.append(PathElement(type: Int(elementType.rawValue), points: points))
    }
    
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        return try encoder.encode(elements)
    } catch {
        return Data()
    }
}

func decode(data: Data) throws -> CGPath {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let elements = try decoder.decode([PathElement].self, from: data)

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    
    for elem in elements {
        switch elem.type {
        case 0:
            path.move(to: elem.points![0])
        case 1:
            path.addLine(to: elem.points![0])
        case 2:
            path.addQuadCurve(to: elem.points![1], control: elem.points![0])
        case 3:
            path.addCurve(to: elem.points![2], control1: elem.points![0], control2: elem.points![1])
        case 4:
            path.closeSubpath()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return path
}

func numPoints(forType type: CGPathElementType) -> Int
{
    var n = 0
    
    switch type {
    case .moveToPoint:
        n = 1
    case .addLineToPoint:
        n = 1
    case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
        n = 2
    case .addCurveToPoint:
        n = 3
    case .closeSubpath:
        n = 0
    default:
        n = 0
    }
    
    return n
}


struct PathElement: Codable {
    var type: Int
    var points: Array<CGPoint>?
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Comment: Awk. For some reason this is exponentially increasing the size. Using NSKeyedArchiver directly on the path results in a 5MB data file, whereas encoding it using this encode method results in a 28MB file. Any idea how to improve on the 5MB one?

Comment: Can you show in more detail how you currently save the path? How many paths add up to 5MB (or 28MB)? Are you working on iOS or macOS?

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is entirely subjective, and depends entirely on your needs and priorities. Is human-readability important? Is data size important? Compatibility with existing APIs somewhere? Those are questions that you need answers to in order to determine what's right for your use-case.

If human-readability of the data is important, then JSON is a clear winner over `NSCoding`. If size is important, then *compressed* JSON is usually smaller than `NSKeyedArchiver` data, but can also be much larger when decompressed.

A small (*non-production-ready*) test harness for generating some random paths and producing data from them:

```
import Foundation
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

extension GKRandom {
    func nextCGFloat(upperBound: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        CGFloat(nextUniform()) * upperBound
    }
    
    func nextCGPoint(scale: CGFloat = 100) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: nextCGFloat(upperBound: scale),
                y: nextCGFloat(upperBound: scale))
    }
    
    func nextCGRect(widthScale: CGFloat = 100, heightScale: CGFloat = 100) -> CGRect {
        CGRect(origin: nextCGPoint(),
               size: CGSize(width: 4 + nextCGFloat(upperBound: widthScale - 4),
                            height: 4 + nextCGFloat(upperBound: heightScale - 4)))
    }
    
    func nextCGPath() -> CGMutablePath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: nextCGPoint())
        
        let minPathElements = 3
        for _ in minPathElements ..< minPathElements + nextInt(upperBound: 10) {
            switch nextInt(upperBound: 6) {
            case 0:
                path.addArc(center: nextCGPoint(),
                            radius: nextCGFloat(upperBound: 20),
                            startAngle: nextCGFloat(upperBound: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi)),
                            endAngle: nextCGFloat(upperBound: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi)),
                            clockwise: nextBool())
                        
            case 1:
                path.addCurve(to: nextCGPoint(),
                              control1: nextCGPoint(),
                              control2: nextCGPoint())
                            
            case 2:
                path.addEllipse(in: nextCGRect())
                
            case 3:
                path.addLine(to: nextCGPoint())
                
            case 4:
                path.addQuadCurve(to: nextCGPoint(),
                                  control: nextCGPoint())
                                
            case 5:
                path.addRect(nextCGRect())
                            
            default:
                continue
            }
        }
        
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

func encodePathWithArchiver(_ path: CGMutablePath) -> Data {
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: path)
    return try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: bezierPath, requiringSecureCoding: true)
}

extension CGPathElement: Encodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case type
        case points
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(type.rawValue, forKey: .type)
        
        let pointCount: Int
        switch type {
        case .moveToPoint, .addLineToPoint, .addQuadCurveToPoint:
            pointCount = 2
        
        case .addCurveToPoint:
            pointCount = 3
            
        case .closeSubpath: fallthrough
        @unknown default:
            pointCount = 0
        }
        
        try container.encode(Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: points, count: pointCount)), forKey: .points)
    }
}

func encodePathAsJSON(_ path: CGMutablePath) -> Data {
    var elements = [CGPathElement]()
    path.applyWithBlock { element in
        elements.append(element.pointee)
    }
    
    return try! JSONEncoder().encode(elements)
}

let randomSource = GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource(seed: 0 /* some reproducible seed here, or omit for a random run each time */)
let path = randomSource.nextCGPath()

let keyedArchiverData = encodePathWithArchiver(path)
let jsonData = encodePathAsJSON(path)
print(keyedArchiverData.count, "<=>", jsonData.count)

let compressedArchiverData = try! (keyedArchiverData as NSData).compressed(using: .lzma) as Data
let compressedJSONData = try! (jsonData as NSData).compressed(using: .lzma) as Data
print(compressedArchiverData.count, "<=>", compressedJSONData.count)
```

The above code uses GameplayKit for reproducible randomness using a seed: you can play around with this to see various results. For example, a seed of `0` produces JSON data that is smaller than `NSKeyedArchiver` data both when compressed and when uncompressed, but a seed of `14283523348572255252` produces JSON data >2× larger than `NSKeyedArchiver` data until compressed.

The takeaway here will largely depend on your *specific* use-case, and what your priorities for data storage are.

---

Note: it's easy to look at small numbers here and try to draw conclusions about what's "best", but keep in mind the scale here: unless your paths are many thousands of points long, the *effective* difference between these methods results in negligible size differences. Whether you put the effort into maintaining an encoding interface for `CGPath` references or whether you go with the one-liner conversion to `UIBezierPath` may make more of a difference to you than any size savings.